# Numerical integration with nested integral

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I want to calculate the ratio G(t) between the two functions B(t) and A(t) at each time step from t=1 to 2500 using MATLAB.

The function A(t) is given by

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnXUk.jpg)

and the function B(t) which has a nested integral, requiring numerical integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVasQ.jpg)

Here j,m,b,d,e,g,h are constants.

I have written following Matlab code for this problem:

```
Functionscript.m

b=0.0001;
m=0.2331;
j=-0.2323;
d=0.1719;
e=-4.5000;
g=0.1719;
h=0.2355;
T=2500;
[G]=QM(b,m,j,d,e,g,h,T);
```

========================================

```
function [G]=QM(b,m,j,d,e,g,h,T)
G=zeros(T);
A=@(t) j-m*coth((m/2)*(t-T)+acoth((j-b)/m));
I=@(t,s) exp(integral(@(u) -A(u)-h,t,s));
SI=@(t,s) I(t,s)*(A(s)*e-g);
B=@(t) I(t,T)*d-integral(@(s) SI(t,s),t,T,'ArrayValued',1);
G(1)=B(1)/A(1);
for i=1:T
G(i)=B(i)/A(i);
end
```

When i run this code the values that I get don't change much over time, I think it is probably because the numerical integration of nested integral is not working correctly. Could anyone please check?. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really the place for code review. Please tell us why you think nested integral is not working. and provide MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the value of the function B(t) doesn't change much over time, if you look at the function B(t), its value should vary considerably overtime. I've tried to make the example as much smaller I could, the original problem is way larger.